# Another noodle boiling effect - bubbling when pushing noodles down

Tags: everyday-life, phase-transition, home-experiment

The very day I read a noodle boiling question here, I discovered the following effect:

1. Noodles (German Spätzle to be exact) were boiling in a standard open pot. Salted water.
2. I turned down the heat and naturally the bubbling stopped after a while
3. The noodles were all floating near the top
4. For some reason, I was using a plastic spatula to stir the noodles
5. **Now the effect:** When **pushing them down** with the spatula, the **bubbling started again**. Instantly. It also was pretty noisy. Lots of small bubbles, unlike the big ones during 'standard' boiling.
6. I was not a one-time effect, I could reproduce it over and over and again 2 minutes later.

I thought this would be an amusing question to ask here, especially because my intuition would suggest the opposite effect. Intentionally, I'm not posting my speculations, because I don't want to bias answers.

Answer (score 1):

> I turned down the heat and the bubbling stopped after a while

You are still heating, it means that the cooling happening at the top level keeps the water below boiling point. The level of noodles going down, reduces the volume to be heated from the full pot to half of the pot, so the heat supplied is enough for the water below the noodles to reach  the boiling point. (my guess)

Comment: That's correct. +1 from me.

Comment: On a serious note: Can't see what you mean by 'volume change'. Also no 'reaching' of boiling point, because it bubbled immediately. Maybe I should post a video, but seems non-standard.

Comment: I mean that the noodles in the middle act like cover would act, if you covered the whole pot, reflect  radiation of the volume beneath them so that the temperature can rise to the boiling point temperature. It all depends on the amount of heat you still have going, after lowering. It bubbles immediately because it obviously is very close to 100C , the water below the noodles can reach it fast  because the volume is halved, whereas the full pot cannot, the heat is not enough to cross the 100C

Comment: Sorry, but the way you talk about 'halved volume' and 'amount of heat' makes me question everything. It's not that the heat is looking for the noodles, or is it?

Comment: The heat in a pot on the fire boils the water faster if  the cover is on the pot, then if not, because the cover reflects radiation, (radiation is the way  things cool) into the pot and the boiling point is reached faster. The layer of noodles in the middle of the water in the pot acts as a type of reflector ,a pot cover, which affects the  amount of radiation leaving the volume of water below the noodles. At the critical point of 100 C, this will make a difference, i.e. where the layer of noodles is, because the volume heated changes, if it is at the top or middle.